# RegEx conversion Javascript to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, regex

currently I'm using the following RegEx in a Javascript code of mine:

```
'(?:' + tags + '):([\\s\\S]*?)(?=\\s+(?:' + tags + '|END):)'
```

..as it's a dynamic RegEx, the variable 'tags' is used for the several parameters i want to filter for.

How would the RegEx look like in PHP code?
I get the following part work:

```
(?:' + tags + '):([\\s\\S]*?)
```

But the second part wont work with PHP, no matter what I try:

```
(?=\\s+(?:' + tags + '|END):)
```

Thank you for your help!

Edit 1:

My current PHP code looks like this:

```
$regexp = '(?:'.$tags.'):([\\s\\S]*?)(?=\\s+(?:'.$tags.'|END):)';
```

Edit 2:

I'm trying to find the following tags/parameters:

```
$tags = 'X-WR-CALNAME|X-WR-TIMEZONE|X-WR-CALDESC|BEGIN|CLASS|DTSTAMP|UID|CREATED|LAST-MODIFIED|SEQUENCE|STATUS|TRANSP|X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS|ORGANIZER|SUMMARY|DESCRIPTION|LOCATION|DTSTART|DTEND|END';
```

...out of a text which looks like this:

> BEGIN:VEVENT
>   DTSTART:20121117T143000Z
>   DTEND:20121117T163000Z
>   DTSTAMP:20121130T185808Z
>   UID:n3f3qjgtads37phsq3oovmvouc@google.com
>   CREATED:20121102T191518Z
>   DESCRIPTION:1. Bundesliga\, 12. Spieltag \n\nhttp://www.fussball-spielplan.
>    info
>   LAST-MODIFIED:20121117T170303Z
>   LOCATION:Imtech-Arena\, Hamburg
>   SEQUENCE:0
>   STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   SUMMARY:Hamburger SV - 1. FSV Mainz 05 (1:0)
>   TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
>   END:VEVENT

..in order to get the value right next to the appropriate tag/parameter.

Comment: This might sound silly, but you're making sure to concat the strings with `.` and not `+`, right? Can you show us your PHP code?

Comment: Sorry my fault, I should have added my PHP code right from the beginning...

Comment: And what does the final regex look like? What are you trying to match (there might be another way, show us an example of the full text and what should be matched - maybe a link to a [RegEx101](http://www.regex101.com) permalink)?

Comment: The regex patterns in PHP need [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) too.

Comment: It would help if you paste a sample of the string you are using, and what you want to achieve. I think that way we could give you a valid answer pretty quickly xd

Comment: I've added my current code/idea at 'Edit 2'

Answer (score 0):

The regex seems to work when [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) (the `/` at the start and end of the pattern) are added.

```
$regexp = '/(?:'.$tags.'):([\s\S]*?)(?=\s+(?:'.$tags.'|END):)/';
```

There is no need to escape the `\` in php regex strings unless you are trying to match a literal `"\"` (in which case `'\\\\'` must be used) - although it is fine to do so.